# tput command + how to locate dialog window on the top of the screen

Tags: bash, shell-script, dialog, tput

Is it possible to use the tput command in order to place the dialog window on the top of the screen ?

For example
The following dialog command display the log is running by tail command

```
     dialog --tailbox file.log 10 100
```

by default dialog window is placed in the central of the screen

but I want to place the dialog window on the top ,  not in the central

please advice How to do that??

**about tput command:**

```
   DESCRIPTION
   The  tput utility uses the terminfo database to make the values of terminal- dependent capabilities and informa-
   tion available to the shell (see sh(1)), to initialize or reset the terminal, or  return the long  name  of  the
   requested terminal type.  The result depends upon the capabilityâs type:
```

Answer (score 1):

`tput` is useless for this purpose.  Use dialog's `--begin` option, f.e. `--begin 0 0` will place the window at top left corner of the terminal.